# Map and scatter not working (Mplleaflet)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter

The following code is an attempt to put points on a map via mplleaflet in a Jupyter notebook. It works for the first 3 points but not when including the 4th. It must be something other than this point - I can plot the 4th and 5th together for example. I want to be able to plot all the points including after the pound signs. Any ideas what's going wrong?

```
%matplotlib inline
import mplleaflet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lats = [54.3256, 53.2692, 53.8242, 53.2178] #, 51.9978, 52.42, 53.1658, 54.292, 52.127, 51.505, 51.478, 51.35]
lons = [2.9356, 3.6278, 2.9453, 3.2203] #, 3.275, -1.83, 0.5239, -1.535, 0.956, -1.993, -0.461, 1.3667]
plt.hold(True)

plt.plot(lons, lats, 'rs')

mplleaflet.display()
```

EDIT: I've given up trying to use plt.scatter as this does not seem to work at all.
EDIT 2: seems I just needed to get rid of the 'mplleaflet.display()' suggested in the original code I was trying to make work. Hold is now depreciated however - see alternative below.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with `matplotlib 2.0.2` and `mplleaflet 0.0.5` and `python 2.7.13`. It works fine for me with all your coordinates, using `plt.plot` and `plt.scatter` ([for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q77BR.jpg)), although I did get a message that `plt.hold` is deprecated. Which version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: matplotlib 2.0.0, thinking it might be a python 3 issue?

Comment: Maybe. When you say it doesn't work if you include the 4th point, do you get an error message? Does it produce any plot at all, and if so, does it plot any of the points? You might also try updating to `matplotlib 2.0.2` (the latest stable release), since that contains some bugfixes over `2.0.0`

Comment: Just a blank canvas, no error. Can't help feeling that mplleaflet is unsupported for python 3. Last commit on GitHub was 2 years ago. Looking for a different library altogether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import mplleaflet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lats = [54.3256, 53.2692, 53.8242, 53.2178]
lons = [2.9356, 3.6278, 2.9453, 3.2203] 

fig = plt.figure()    #This is missing in your code.
plt.plot(lons, lats, 'r.')

#And after this call the funtion:

mplleaflet.display(fig=fig)
#It will display the matplotlib object created by plot function
```

Comment: Some additional information to this answer:
Even though the points are displayed in a matplotlib plot there can be the following reasons mplleaflet will not work:
Be sure that no nan values are in the list.
Be sure that it is a list and no numpy array or similar.